# How can I assign a integer value to each HTML element inside the array returned with querySelectorAll selector

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to create a calculator, The way I am thinking of it is getting the array of 'number' class with querySelectorAll. Then iterate through each element of the array returned and store all the numbers clicked in "firstOperand" but I don't know how to assign a value to each HTML element to be for example, the first HTML element = 1, second HTML element = 2. I am open to hear new solutions for this code, I know it is not exactly best formatted and perfect code but I am so new to this, thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="button number">1</div>
<div class="button number">2</div>
```

Javascript:

```
let numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number')

let numberClicked;

numbers.forEach(number => {
    number.addEventListener('click', function() {
        let firstOperand = screen.innerText += numberClicked;
        console.log(firstOperand);
    })
});
```

Comment: HTML `value`s and text are Strings. You need to cast them to numbers. Also, `numberClicked` is `undefined`, so its not a number. You may want to research the floating point issue, as well.

Comment: The forEach methods do not work in nodeList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you were mostly doing it right but just were not looking for the value in the correct place, Added a bit of CSS to make a beautiful Calculator:

```js
let numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number')
let calculatorScreen = document.getElementById('calculatorScreen');

numbers.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        calculatorScreen.value = calculatorScreen.value + el.innerText;
    });
});
```

```css
html {
     font-size: 62.5%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 *, *::before, *::after {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: inherit;
}
 .calculator {
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-radius: 5px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     width: 400px;
}
 .calculator-screen {
     width: 100%;
     height: 80px;
     border: none;
     background-color: #252525;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: right;
     padding-right: 20px;
     padding-left: 10px;
     font-size: 4rem;
}
 button {
     height: 60px;
     font-size: 2rem!important;
}
 .equal-sign {
     height: 98%;
     grid-area: 2 / 4 / 6 / 5;
}
 .calculator-keys {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
     grid-gap: 20px;
     padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator card">
   <input type="text" id="calculatorScreen" class="calculator-screen z-depth-1" value="" disabled />
   <div class="calculator-keys">
      <button type="button" value="+">+</button>
      <button type="button" value="-">-</button>
      <button type="button" value="*">&times;</button>
      <button type="button" value="/">&divide;</button>
      <button type="button" value="7" class="number">7</button>
      <button type="button" value="8" class="number">8</button>
      <button type="button" value="9" class="number">9</button>
      <button type="button" value="4" class="number">4</button>
      <button type="button" value="5" class="number">5</button>
      <button type="button" value="6" class="number">6</button>
      <button type="button" value="1" class="number">1</button>
      <button type="button" value="2" class="number">2</button>
      <button type="button" value="3" class="number">3</button>
      <button type="button" value="0" class="number">0</button>
      <button type="button" value=".">.</button>
      <button type="button" value="all-clear">AC</button>
      <button type="button" class="equal-sign" value="=">=</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can get the value by e.target.innerHTML

```js
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number')
const screen = document.getElementById('screen')

numbers.forEach(number => {
  number.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    screen.innerHTML += e.target.innerHTML
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="button number">1</div>
<div class="button number">2</div>
<div class="button number">3</div>
<div class="button number">4</div>
<div class="button number">5</div>
<div class="button number">6</div>
<div class="button number">7</div>
<div class="button number">8</div>
<div class="button number">9</div>
<div class="button number">0</div>
<div>==============screen========</div>
<div id="screen"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am open to hear new solutions for this code

`forEach` provides the index as the second parameter, which we can handily use as the `innerText` of the element currently looping through.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach((e, i)=>{
  e.innerText = i;
})
```

```html
<div class="button number"></div>
<div class="button number"></div>
<div class="button number"></div>
<div class="button number"></div>
<div class="button number"></div>
<div class="button number"></div>
<div class="button number"></div>
<div class="button number"></div>
<div class="button number"></div>
<div class="button number"></div>
```